# RESTfully change operation behaviour

Tags: rest

**The Situation:**

Via `POST` operation, users can create a new resource based on given parameters. If there already exists a resource created from these same parameters, the existing resource is returned instead.

Users are able to `GET` this resource if they know the resource ID (generated on creation, and is effectively random). I would like to provide users a way to check existence only knowing the creation parameters and without creating a new resource.

**The Question:**

Would it be RESTful to take some kind of "just-checking" property in the `POST` body to prevent a new resource from being created?

**An Example:**

```
POST vehicle
{
    colour: 'red',
    wheels: 4
}

201: {
    vehicleId: '314-159',
    colour: 'red',
    wheels: 4
}
```

---

```
GET vehicle/314-159

200: {
    vehicleId: '314-159',
    colour: 'red',
    wheels: 4
}
```

---

```
POST vehicle
{
    colour: 'red',
    wheels: 4,
    check: true
}

200: {
    vehicleId: '314-159',
    colour: 'red',
    wheels: 4
}


POST vehicle
{
    colour: 'blue',
    wheels: 8,
    check: true
}

404: Not Found
```

**Edit**

Much of the discussion has been around whether the `POST` operation should be idempotent, which, while valid, does not address my question.

I would like to provide my users with a way to validate the existence of a resource based only on the properties that would be used to create the resource.

The idempotency of the `POST` method is irrelevant. What suffers from the absence of this check is subsequent `GET` requests which will contain a number of resources that are never intended to be used, and make it more difficult to find useful information.

A `POST` request containing a "do-not-create" flag would fill this need, but may not *feel* RESTful.

Comment: Yes you can, but i would suggest to use ‘409 conflict‘ response code if entity exist and 200 if entity is created.

Comment: yea 409 is much better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, the solution chosen was to add options for a special case on the `GET` method.

As touched on in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49765427/9626702), it is not quite in the spirit of the `POST` method to perform this type of operation, and it muddies the model being presented to the users.

Answer (score 1):

How about implementing an idempotent post? In doing so you could avoid the “check” body param.

Comment: The issue with an idempotent post (if I understand the term correctly) is that it would cause "junk resources" to be created when checking existence. This can cause the undesirable situation of users having to wade through mostly empty resource objects when retrieving lists. Another option being considered is more robust filtering capabilities, but the proposed method seems much more straight-forward (assuming it isn't a REST no-no).

Comment: U mean to say put?

Comment: What I mean by an idempotent post is that no matter how many times such a post request is submitted, you would always get the same reponse. This is particularly useful when you want to support retry capabailities. There are various ways how this can be implemented but a simple solution that comes to mind is that you first lookup by colour and wheels and return the found instance, if any, or create a new one. In doing so, your clients need not worry about changing the request when attempting a retry.

Comment: If idempotency is not an option, what I believe is more restful than posting a request as you described to check existence is to allow filtering on the vehicles collection resource. So, to check if a red vehicle with 4 wheels exists, submit a get on /vehicles?wheels=4&colour=red which would return a list of all matching vehicles. If you need more complex criteria, you can look into RQL.

Answer (score 0):

2 ideas:

**Use PUT and natural keys**

One option (not sure if this works for you) is to *not* use some database-id in the url but use something that's a bit more like a natural key.

So instead of POSTing on some collection, you just PUT the item:

```
PUT /vehicles/colour/blue/wheels/8
```

`PUT` can also be used for creation just fine. And you could use a header such as this to prevent overwriting existing values:

```
If-None-Match: *
```

**Don't put it on the client to do this**

What if a `POST` for creating an item is identical to updating it? Or, what if you call `POST` on an existing item, it just doesn't actually do anything.

Maybe the client doesn't need to know if it just created a new item, or if the server already had that item.

Just make sure that for those 2 cases the server behaves the same, and you should be good.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ID is used throughout the system, so it must stay. As mentioned in another comment, the main goal here is to provide the client a way to avoid overwhelming themselves with unused resources.

Comment: @Curtis did you read my second solution? Basically what I'm saying, just 'pretend' the POST succeeded, send back a 200 OK and return the current state.

Comment: This is the same solution @SarahCassar suggested. It might be worth reading it again and spend some more time figuring out what she means with idempotent. It does not mean creating junk resources, quite the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

> Users are able to GET this resource if they know the resource ID (generated on creation, and is effectively random). I would like to provide users a way to check existence only knowing the creation parameters and without creating a new resource.

How would you do it with a web site?

Probably, with a form, that would accept as inputs the same creation parameters.  The user is in effect performing a search, which is a semantically safe operation, so the form would likely use the GET method and have the arguments from the form encoded into the query string.

The endpoint, on receiving that request, could redirect it to the appropriate resource (if one already exists) or to another resource to handle the case when it doesn't.

> Would it be RESTful to take some kind of "just-checking" property in the POST body to prevent a new resource from being created?

Sure - again, how would you do this on a web site?  The form would have an extra checkbox, set to the correct default behavior, but giving the user the option to change it before submitting the form.

Because switching the check box changes the semantics from a safe operation to an unsafe operation, you might want to change the method on the form during submission -- HTML by itself doesn't do that, but you can do it with javascript aka [code on demand](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_7).

Using POST for [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) operations isn't ideal, because generic components can't *tell* that the operation is safe.  This means that they can't know to automatically retry the request if the response is lost, they don't have the correct default cache behaviors, and so on.